# Resource file cannot contain any tests or tasks - Robot File

Tags: testing, robotframework

I have a main robot script that references keywords from a resource file. The resource file contains the tests to be run, and I simply call the functionalities from my main robot script. I am receiving the following error:

```
Resource file cannot contain any tests or tasks
```

What might be the cause for this, and how do I go about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 4):

From the Robot Framework Guide on [Resource Files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-file-structure):

> The higher-level structure of resource files is the same as that of
>   test case files otherwise, but, of course, they **cannot contain Test**
>   **Case tables**.

In summary: Test Case files need to contain test cases and *can* contain keywords. Resource files also *can* contain keywords (they do not need to) but *do not* contain test cases.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. The issue is we can't use all the OO concepts as we are not using python directly. You can contain your variables and keywords in resource files.
As a solution what you can do is write your test case (that you want to import) as a keyword and then use the keyword inside the test case.
If you leave the ***Test cases*** section empty in the file that you are going to execute, Robot will think you have no test cases to execute.
So, Think of keywords as public methods then you'll solve the issue :)